# ¿Como puedo dejar ejecutando mis servicios en máquina virtual de google cloud al cerrar mi sesión SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, wildfly, ssh

Tengo una instancia de Ubutu ejecutándose en google cloud, el conectarme por SSH y subir un servidor de aplicaciones Wildfly 10 sube correctamente, pero al salir de la sesión, el proceso se termina.

¿Como puedo seguir ejecutando el proceso al cerrar la consola SSH?

Gracias.

Comment: Una solución es instalar `screen`, con este paquete puede una o más sesiones en su terminal ssh. Este recurso lo puede guiar https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen

Comment: Gracias por la solución

Answer (score 0):

Si por supuesto solamente tienes que ejecutar el siguiente comando antes del proceso `nohup proceso`, por ejemplo si vas a ejecutar un binario seria de la siguiente forma `nohup ./main`, en caso de estar en python `nohup python script.py`